# DataPipe Export Location

Tags: angular, jhipster

In the updated Angular2 generator the `shared.module.ts` [exports](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/client/templates/angular/src/main/webapp/app/shared/_shared.module.ts#L78) the `DataPipe` from `@angular/common`.  Is there a reason this is in the `shared.module` and not in the `shared-lib.module`?

Just trying to make sure I understand everything that is happening